# ¿Por que no carga la imagen del Glide dentro de un CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap?

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, kotlin, glide

Al ejecutar el **onMapReady** llamo a una función llamada setUpReport(){} dentro de esa función hay un marker.tag que llama a una clase **CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap**. El problema es que no carga las imagenes de Glide.

El codigo de CostumInfoWindowGoogleMap es el siguiente:

```
class CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap(val context: Context) : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    override fun getInfoContents(p0: Marker?): View {

        val mInfoView = (context as Activity).layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.reportvisor_maps, null)
        val mInfoWindow: ReportPet? = p0?.tag as ReportPet?

        mInfoView.title_window.text = mInfoWindow?.mTitleReport
        mInfoView.date_ReportVisor.text = mInfoWindow?.mDate
        mInfoView.description_ReportVisor.text = mInfoWindow?.mdescriptionReport
        mInfoView.type_ReportVisor.text = mInfoWindow?.mTypeReport
        val imageReportVisor = mInfoView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_ReportVisor)
        Glide.with(this.context).load(mInfoWindow?.mImageReport).into(imageReportVisor) // image
        Log.d("IMGREPORT","mImageReport: ${mInfoWindow?.mImageReport}")

        return mInfoView
    }

    override fun getInfoWindow(p0: Marker?): View? {
        return null
    }
}
```

Lo invoco con:

```
private fun setUpReport(){
         for (reportPet in listReport){
                        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
                        markerOptions
                            .position(LatLng(reportPet.mGeoPoint.latitude,reportPet.mGeoPoint.longitude))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.iconmapblue))
                        val customInfoWindow = CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap(this)
                        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(customInfoWindow)
                        val marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
                        marker.tag = reportPet
                        marker.showInfoWindow()
           }
}
```

Comment: tienes un ejemplo de la url que imprime el Log :  Log.d("IMGREPORT","mImageReport: ${mInfoWindow?.mImageReport}") ? esto es importante conocerlo

Comment: D/IMGREPORT: mImageReport: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mappet-be63d.appspot.com/o/report%2F79993ku%40gmail.com?alt=media&token=f1af4dbd-5d33-4b46-b9b7-7d72760211f8

Comment: Logcat `D/IMGREPORT: mImageReport: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mappet-be63d.appspot.com/o/report%2F80030zero%40gmail.com?alt=media&token=92eb95c4-0487-4636-8785-29c38f377cdb`

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar el permiso para uso de internet dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

posiblemente algunas url que se cargan usando `Glide` no esten usando `https://` si no  `http://`, para esto no cause problema activa el uso de trafico ClearText dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<application
        ...
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Los permisos de INTERNET ya estaban.

Comment: Escribí lo que  faltaba en "Application". La imagen todavía no se muestra.  Al cargar una imagen con Glide me aparece esto en el Logcat: `W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored`

Comment: ok que bien que obtuviste informaciòn del LogCat entonces  agrega el build.gradle por favor

Comment: Implementado: `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0`         
    Todavia no carga la imagen pero creo que el problema tiene que ver el cache. 
LogCat:               `I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=505KB, data=357KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=504KB, data=357KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB`

Comment: Al parecer se trata de una mala implementación del Glide. No se como se implementa el modulo correcto que yo necesito. http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#avoid-appglidemodule-in-libraries

Comment: Pude implementar correctamente el AppGlide (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/379402/kotlin-como-implementar-correctamente-glidemodule/380292#380292) pero la imagen todavía no aparece en el InfoWindow.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente pude poner imagenes en el InfoWindow de googlemaps:

```
//class InfoWindowAdapter
    inner class CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap(private val context: Context) : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter{
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        override fun getInfoWindow(p0: Marker?): View? {
            val mInfoWindow: ReportPet? = p0?.tag as ReportPet?
            val mInfoView = when(mInfoWindow!!.mTypeMarker){
                "yellow"-> (context as Activity).layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.reportvisor_maps, null)
                "red"-> (context as Activity).layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.reportpetlostvisor_maps, null)
                else-> (context as Activity).layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.reportvisor_maps, null)
            }

            mInfoView.title_window.text = mInfoWindow.mTitle
            mInfoView.date_ReportVisor.text = mInfoWindow.mFormatDate
            mInfoView.description_ReportVisor.text = mInfoWindow.mDescription
            mInfoView.type_ReportVisor.text = mInfoWindow.mTypePet

            Picasso.get()
                .load(mInfoWindow.mImage)
                //.placeholder(R.drawable.gif_loading)
                .into(mInfoView.findViewById(R.id.image_ReportVisor), object : Callback {
                    override fun onSuccess() {
                        if (p0 != null && p0.isInfoWindowShown) {
                            p0.hideInfoWindow()
                            p0.showInfoWindow()
                        }
                    }
                    override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
                        Log.e("TAG","Error loading avatar to info window!  image: ${mInfoView.id}")
                    }
                })
            return mInfoView
        }

        override fun getInfoContents(p0: Marker?): View? {
            return null
        }
    }
```